# x509 authentication with spring security 2.0.4

Tags: spring-security, x509certificate

i am new to spring security.
can anybody provide me sample application for x509 certificate authentication with spring 2.0.4

Answer (score 0):

You can use the basic `<http>` setup to get X509 authentication:

```
<http>
   <x509: subject-principal-regex"(.*)" user-service-ref="myUserService"/>
   <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER" requires-channel="https"/>
</http>
```